# how can I know whether my hardwood floor is glued down or nailed down?

Tags: hardwood-floor

I am not sure whether the floor is glued down. If yes, it will be a big challenge for me to replace it in the future...

Is there anyway to identify whether it's glued down or nailed down?

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Judging by your picture, this appears to be a site-finished hardwood floor. That means it would be installed and then sanded and varnished on-site, and the clearest signal of this is that the floor is one smooth surface, with no bevels or texture changes you can feel by hand at the edges of each floorboard.

Assuming that's true, then **it's almost certainly tongue-and-groove slats, nailed or stapled through the tongues.** Some boards around the edges may be face-nailed. That's the most common way these floors have been installed for decades, though it's not impossible to imagine it was glued.

In any case it seems like a beautiful floor, and you can change the look by sanding, staining, and refinishing without pulling up the existing floor.

Comment: This floor appears to be in great condition. Is it on a concrete slab?

Comment: Thanks! Yes, the floor seems in very good condition. I am not going to replace it in many years probably but just curious about the possibility.

Comment: @Jim Stewart its on wood subfloor I think...

Comment: What is the foundation of the house, slab, full basement, pier-and-beam?

Answer (score 2):

You can look around the perimeter of the room for nails. If you see nails it is nailed. If you don't though it doesn't necessarily mean it is glued.

A flooring nailer cannot be used near walls. On the first few rows you can use other means to blind nail the boards (finish nailer, drill/hammer, etc) but on the last 1-2 rows there's not enough room for that. Instead the last few boards would be face nailed (nails in the top). The holes would be filled with a little putty. If you can carefully look for these and you see some nails then it is nailed. If you see none it might still be nailed because someone was just good at either filling the holes, getting a nail into a tight spot or covering the nail with the baseboards.

A third option is it is neither. Some floors are floating floors and are neither glued or nailed.

Answer (score 2):

If you have a rare-earth magnet, you can scan the floor with it to find where the nails are.